# Getting all occurrences of max per one distinct value in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to query per decade film with highest rating(or films if there are 2 with highest(max) rating). I am nearly there and my only issue is that if there are 2 films in a decade(with same rating(max rating)), it does not query it. I have tried a lot of different things but nothing seems to work.
So far I got

```
SELECT FLOOR(premiered / 10) * 10 AS Decades,
       title,
       rating
  FROM titles
       INNER JOIN
       ratings ON titles.title_id = ratings.title_id 
 GROUP BY decades
```

Which returns:

```
1920    The Kid 8.3
1930    City Lights 8.5
1940    It's a Wonderful Life   8.6
1950    12 Angry Men    9
1960    The Good, the Bad and the Ugly  8.8
1970    The Godfather   9.2
1980    Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back  8.7
1990    The Shawshank Redemption    9.3
2000    The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King   9
2010    Inception   8.8
2020    Jai Bhim    8.9
```

My schema looks like:

**titles**

```
title_id
title
premiered -> this is the year of movie's release
```

**ratings**

```
title_id
rating
```

I am not sure how I can get all occurrences of max(rating) per decade(sqlite).
My desired result is to get something like this

```
1920    The Kid 8.3
1920    Another_movie_with_matching_max(rating) 8.3
```

**EDIT**:
Jarlh suggested to use a subquery to get max rating per decade. I figured it out

```
SELECT FLOOR(premiered / 10) * 10 AS Decades,
                  rating as rat
             FROM ratings
                  JOIN
                  titles ON ratings.title_id = titles.title_id
            GROUP BY decades
           HAVING max(rating)
```

Now I am just not sure how to use this subquery to get all films. I tried ->

```
SELECT FLOOR(premiered / 10) * 10 AS Decades,
       title,
       rating
  FROM titles
       INNER JOIN
       ratings ON titles.title_id = ratings.title_id 
where decades and RATING = (
           SELECT FLOOR(premiered / 10) * 10,
                  rating as rat
             FROM ratings
                  JOIN
                  titles ON ratings.title_id = titles.title_id
            GROUP BY FLOOR(premiered / 10) * 10
           HAVING max(rating) 
           )
           GROUP BY decades
```

Which does not work as intended

Comment: You need to JOIN a subqeury returning each decade with its max rating. Or use a window function (if supported, I don't know sqlite.)

Comment: How would that subquery look like?

Comment: Similar to what you have, GROUP BY, MAX etc'

Comment: @jarlh I figured out the subquery,  SELECT FLOOR(premiered / 10) * 10 AS Decades, rating as rat FROM ratings JOIN  titles ON ratings.title_id = titles.title_id GROUP BY decades HAVING max(rating)(this returns max rating per decade). How can I use it in conjunction with my main query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Had to use IN() instead of joining the two tables together.

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(premiered / 10)*10 AS str AS decades, rating, title
FROM ratings
JOIN titles ON titles.title_id = ratings.title_id
WHERE (decades, rating) IN
    (SELECT FLOOR(premiered / 10)*10AS decades, MAX(rating)
    FROM ratings
    JOIN titles ON titles.title_id = ratings.title_id
    GROUP BY decades) ORDER BY decades ASC;
```